# how to convert created_at column data as table header laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, eloquent

hi forum  how to convert created_at column as header table and synchronized it with title column.
this is my database
[image: my data base]

below is my blade code

```
    <div class="container">           
    <table class="table table-striped"> 
        <thead>  
            <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    @foreach($users as $u=>$user)
                        @foreach($user->posts as $p)
                        <th>{{$p->created_at}}</th>
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
            </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $u=>$user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$u+1}}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
            @foreach($user->posts as $p)
            <td><a href ="/posts/{{$p->id}}">{{$p->title}}</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
          </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

this is my blade view
[image: my blade view]

i have 2 table, user table and post table. a user could have many posts.

this is my post model

[image: my post model]

this is my user model

[image: user model]

this my post controller

[image: my post controller]

thank you.

Comment: your question is not quite clear. please add your code as code and not as image. and explain your problem more specifically with your expected output format.

Comment: do not put up pictures of code, code is text, you can copy and paste into a code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect all `created_at` in a new array with the help of [`@php`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#php) directive and use 2 nested loops for comparison while displaying.

Run over all `created_at` and check if any of the post's timing matches. If yes, display the anchor tag and break out of the loop. If none of them matches, print an empty `td`.

```
<div class="container">           
<table class="table table-striped"> 
    <thead>  
        <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                @php
                    $created_ats = []
                @endphp
                @foreach($users as $u => $user)
                    @foreach($user->posts as $p)
                    <th>{{ $p->created_at }}</th>
                    @php
                        $created_ats[] = $p->created_at
                    @endphp
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $u => $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$u+1}}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
            @foreach($created_ats as $created_at)
                @foreach($user->posts as $p)
                    @if($p->created_at == $created_at)
                        <td><a href ="/posts/{{$p->id}}">{{$p->title}}</a></td>
                        @break
                    @endif
                    @if($loop->last)
                        <td></td>
                    @endif
                @endforeach         
            @endforeach        
        </tr> 
    @endforeach   
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

---

If you want dates in sorted format, collect all of them in your controller, `usort` them with the help of `DateTime` class and pass them to the view.

**Controller code:**

```
<?php 

public function index(){
    $users = User:all();
    $created_ats = [];
    foreach($users as $u=>$user){
        foreach($user->posts as $p){
            $created_ats[] = $p->created_at;
        }
    }

    usort($created_ats,function($date1,$date2){
        $date1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);
        $date2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date2);
        return $date1 <=> $date2; // needs PHP7 minimum
    });

    return view('posts.index',compact('users','created_ats'));
}
```

**Blade:**

```
<div class="container">           
<table class="table table-striped"> 
    <thead>  
        <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                @foreach($created_ats as $created_at)
                    <th>{{ $created_at }}</th>
                @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $u => $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$u+1}}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
            @foreach($created_ats as $created_at)
                @foreach($user->posts as $p)
                    @if($p->created_at == $created_at)
                        <td><a href ="/posts/{{$p->id}}">{{$p->title}}</a></td>
                        @break
                    @endif
                    @if($loop->last)
                        <td></td>
                    @endif
                @endforeach         
            @endforeach        
        </tr> 
    @endforeach   
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: whoaaaa thank you @nice_dev . its been more than a years i tried to solve this issue. btw as the last begging would you like to advice me to seried the header from the lower date to the higher one e.r date 1, 2,3,45,5,....and so forth

Comment: @Enthusiast You will have to `sort` them by collecting them in an array and then pass them to the view.

Comment: brohhh i know the concept but not the code technics, as far as i know it might be using query builder with groupBy or orderBy. if you dont mind let me know the methode() or the propherties(). thank you in advance.

Comment: thank you brother @nice_dev. all works as expected. greetings from indonesia